# Как добавить #якорь в адресную строку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на якорь, к ссылке добавлялся якорь типо https://123.ru/**#anchor**  ? И при нажатии каждого последующего изменялся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Разметка (любое место в пределах body и любой тег):
<section id="onas">Что-то там</section>

Ссылка: 
<a  href="#onas" class="menu-link">О нас</a>
```

Comment: Я так и  сделал, при наведение на ссылку появляется https://123.ru/#anchor , а когда уже нажимаешь на нее переходит к блоку, в url остается только https://123.ru/, а нужно чтобы в адресной строке оставался якорь

Comment: Значит, смотрите обработку url Вашим движком - в стандарте все остается - по смотрите htaccess или в движке соответствующее. Можно,конечно, и поверх костыль подумать - но не стоит - слойный пирожок не оптимально

Comment: Все дело было в плавном скроле, убрал его и заработало

Comment: ) Хорошо, рад !